# How to display data from AJAX in Angular JS calendar?

Tags: angularjs, calendar

I use the following calendar in Angular JS: [angular-bootstrap-calendar](https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-bootstrap-calendar)

I have AJAX method that returns dates for this calendar:

```
$scope.showSchedule = function () {

                appoService.getSchedule().then(function (response) {
                    calendarService.set(response.data.calendar, function (){
                        $scope.refleshCalendar();

                    });
                });
            };
```

Inside callback you can see method `$scope.refleshCalendar();`:

```
$scope.refleshCalendar = function () {
                angular.forEach(calendarService.get(), function (item) {
                    $scope.vm.events.push(item);
                });
            };
```

This methos prepares data to native object `$scope.vm.events` and adds dates to calendar.

At response from AJAX I get array of objects as:

```
[{title: "Ola", type: "info", startsAt: "2015-10-31 17:00:00", resizable: true,…},…]
```

Full object is:

```
{incrementsBadgeTotal: true
recursOn: "year"
resizable: true
startsAt: "2015-10-31 12:00:00"
status: "1"
title: "Ola"
type: "info"}
```

My HTML code of calendar is:

`<mwl-calendar
                                                events="vm.events"
                                                view="vm.calendarView"
                                                view-title="vm.calendarTitle"
                                                current-day="vm.calendarDay"
                                                on-event-click="vm.eventClicked(calendarEvent)"
                                                on-event-times-changed="vm.eventTimesChanged(calendarEvent); calendarEvent.startsAt = calendarNewEventStart; calendarEvent.endsAt = calendarNewEventEnd"
                                                auto-open="true"
                                                day-view-start="06:00"
                                                day-view-end="23:00"
                                                day-view-split="30"
                                                cell-modifier="vm.modifyCell(calendarCell)">
                                            </mwl-calendar>`

Problems is that dates from AJAX is not displayed in this calendar.
I tried all...